# Conditional Formatting Duplicate Invoices in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

My workplace uses Google Sheets to track invoices across all locations.  The two most important columns are next to each other and titled `Invoice number` and `Vendor`. I wanted to highlight the `Invoice number` cell every time there is a duplicate value.  I started with `=countif(A:A,A1)>1`, however, this would highlight any duplicate value, even if the invoices were from two different vendors.  Is it possible to format a Google sheet so it will only highlight the duplicate invoice (column F) if and only if columns F and G are both duplicate values?

Comment: Try `COUNTIFS` since you want to count the rows with more than one criteria, something like `=COUNTIFS(F:F,F1,G:G,G1)>1` should work

Comment: This looks like it has fixed the problem so far, thank you so much!  I had the ">1" inside the parenthesis and this seemed to be the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

- custom formula for highlighting duplicates should look like this:

  ```
  =COUNTIFS(F:F, F1, G:G, G1)>1
  ```